# How to get token in HTTP from Amazon SNS subscription?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, request, amazon-sns

How do I confirm the subscription of Amazon SNS via http? I'm currently using Rails for my application and would like to get notifications of my email bounces. So, I tried looking through Amazon forums and the closest I found was : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=87555 which tells me to use request.raw_post to get the request and the JSON parse it. However, when i tried doing so, it gives me an error saying that the request is empty. Am I doing it the right way? Can someone guide me on how to obtain the subscription token from Amazon SNS so that I can confirm my subscription?

Comment: Yes, parsing the request body should yield a hash containing, among other things, the confirmation token. It would be easier to answer this question if you posted some code.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. In your controller, create an action something like the code below. You wanted the token route, so you can see it there. But I opted for the SubscribeURL route, and just do a GET on the URL.

```
  def sns
     request_json = JSON.parse(request.raw_post, {symbolize_names: true})
     subscribe_url = request_json[:SubscribeURL]
     token = request_json[:Token]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a php scrit that works for me. (There is some Log lines that write it to a file i /tmp/log.txt that helps to debug what's going on. First of all, I  downloaded the amazon cert from https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem Be sure also to work with utf8 everywhere.

For me, it only works with http. I can't see any access in the server when I subscribe an  https url.

```
<?php

mLog ("\n\n----------------Start Receive -------------\n");

require_once APP_DIR . 'util/AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php';

$h= fopen("php://input","r");
$X = stream_get_contents($h);


$J = json_decode( $X , true);

mLog("Received body: \n" . json_encode($J). "\n");

function mLog($Msg) {
    file_put_contents(sys_get_temp_dir() .'/log.txt',$Msg,FILE_APPEND);
}


function CheckCall($J) {

    if ($J["Type"]=="Notification") {
        $SB='';
        $SB .= "Message\n";
        $SB .= $J["Message"] . "\n";
        $SB .= "MessageId\n";
        $SB .= $J["MessageId"] . "\n";

        if ($J["Subject"] != null) {
            $SB .= "Subject\n";
            $SB .= $J["Subject"]. "\n";
        }

        $SB .= "Timestamp\n";
        $SB .= $J["Timestamp"] . "\n";

        $SB .="TopicArn\n";
        $SB .= $J["TopicArn"]."\n";
        $SB .="Type\n";
        $SB .=$J["Type"]."\n";

    } else if ($J["Type"]=="SubscriptionConfirmation") {
        $SB='';
        $SB .= "Message\n";
        $SB .= $J["Message"] . "\n";
        $SB .= "MessageId\n";
        $SB .= $J["MessageId"] . "\n";
        $SB .= "SubscribeURL\n";
        $SB .= $J["SubscribeURL"] . "\n";
        $SB .= "Timestamp\n";
        $SB .= $J["Timestamp"] . "\n";

        $SB .= "Token\n";
        $SB .= $J["Token"] ."\n";
        $SB .="TopicArn\n";
        $SB .= $J["TopicArn"]."\n";
        $SB .="Type\n";
        $SB .=$J["Type"]."\n";
    } else {
        $SB='';
    }


    $cert = file_get_contents('SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem');
    $pubkey_id = openssl_get_publickey($cert);

    mLog("Signed string:\n" . $SB . "End Signed string\n");

    $Sig=base64_decode($J["Signature"]);
    if ( openssl_verify($SB, $Sig, $pubkey_id)) {
        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}

if (!CheckCall($J)) {
    mLog("Authorization failed. \n");
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    echo "<html><head></head><body>".sys_get_temp_dir()."</body></html>";

    exit(0);
}

$sns = new AmazonSNS();

if ($J["Type"]=="SubscriptionConfirmation") {
    $Res = $sns->confirm_subscription($J["TopicArn"], $J["Token"]);
    mLog("confitm_subscription sended: \n" . json_encode($Res));
} else if ($J["Type"]=="Notification") {
    mLog("-----------Begin Message-----------\n");
    mLog("Subject: ".$J["Subject"]. "\n");
    mLog($J["Message"]);
    mLog("\n-----------End Messagr------------\n\n");

} else {
    mLog("Invalid type \n");
}
echo "<html><head></head><body>Authentication Error</body></html>";
```

Answer (score -1):

**WITH PHP:**

You can get in `file_get_contents('php://input');`

You will receive someone like this json structure:

```
{
  "Type" : "SubscriptionConfirmation",
  "MessageId" : "4..050670318",
  "Token" : "2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e2425f00....",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns......",
  "Message" : "You have chosen to subscribe to the topic arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:430......\nTo confirm the subscription, visit the SubscribeURL included in this message.",
  "SubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=ConfirmSubscription&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:us-....&Token=2336412f37fb687f5d51e6e2425f004aef17b3ebbd98e122....",
  "Timestamp" : "2020-06-30T14:31:43.953Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "i3zpoQ3mAbcxTr18m/z5PL9Ls...",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/..."
}
```